How to change author_picture image style in node.html.twig
How to change {{ author_picture }} image style in the node.html.twig.The default style is "thumbnail" , I want to change the image style to a custom style named "mini_avator" but I couldn't find a way to fulfill it.

This is defined in the Compact display mode here:
Administration > Configuration > People > Account settings > Manage display
/admin/config/people/accounts/display/compact
